# AntiXSS HtmlEncode Textarea line break loss

Tags: asp.net, xss, html-encode, antixsslibrary

I am developing web application on ASP.NET and I am getting textarea input from users and later display this input on website. While saving input into database I am not encoding input and directly write them into db.

If input contains "enter" I don't want to lose line breaks. So I am replacing data like that:
Replace("\r\n", "`<br />`")

And to prevent XSS attack before displaying I am encoding data using Microsoft's AntiXSS library's Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode function.

This function also encodes "`<br/>`" and on screen I don't have any line break.

If I encode first with AntiXSS and then replace "\r\n" with "`<br/>`" I am not getting any line break as well, since AntiXSS I think removes "\r\n".

If I use Server.HtmlEncode and then replace "\r\n" with "`<br/>`" then everything is fine. But I want to use AntiXSS library and I don't know how to achieve this.

Is there any way to print line breaks using AntiXSS HtmlEncode function?

Thanks

Comment: After the ```<br/>``` is encoded, can't you then just replace the encoded ```<br/>``` with a decoded version?  e.g. ```Replace("&lt;br/&gt;","<br/>")```?